# Kafka Streams - Creating Windowed State Store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

The below code "works" but I am confused on the meaning on the values passed in Stores.persistentWindowStore().  I found the documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/Stores.html#persistentWindowStore-java.lang.String-long-int-long-boolean-) but the definition of the args is not clear to me.

Should the windowBy() value always match windowSize in persistentWindowStore()?

What should the retention period be set to?  The retention policy of the source topic?

What do the number of segments do?

What are retaining duplicates for?  Document seems to indicate to set to true for joins?

```
long windowSize = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15);
long retentionPeriod = windowSize*4*6 //6 hours
int numSegments = 2;
boolean retainDuplicates = false;

bdrStream.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowSize))
    .aggregate(() -> Lists.newArrayList(),
        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
            BdrData d = new BdrData();
            d.setCharge(newValue.getBdr().getCost());
            aggValue.add(d);
            return aggValue;
        },
        Materialized.<String, ArrayList<BdrData>>as(
            Stores.persistentWindowStore("store5", 
                retentionPeriod, 
                numSegments, 
                windowSize,
                retainDuplicates))
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(listBdrDataSerde))
    .toStream()
    .process(() -> new WindowAggregatorProcessor());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should the windowBy() value always match windowSize in persistentWindowStore()?

Yes.

> What should the retention period be set to? The retention policy of the source topic?

It should match the retention period of the windows, that you can specify via `Windows#until()` (default is 1 day)

> What do the number of segments do?

The number of segments determine how coarse/fine grained data (ie, old windows) are expired. The segment size will be "retention-period / (#segments + 1)". Note, that more segments give you more fine grained data expiration but increases overhead (each segment uses it's own RocksDB instance)

> What are retaining duplicates for? Document seems to indicate to set to true for joins?

By default, keys must be unique. If you enable retain duplicates, you can store the same key multiple times. Enabling duplicates comes with a performance hit.

**Note:**

This part of the API was reworked and simplified in upcoming 2.1 release. Compare [KIP-319](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-319%3A+Replace+segments+with+segmentInterval+in+WindowBytesStoreSupplier) and [KIP-328](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables) for details.

Comment: I could not find any info on Windows#untl looks like all google references are from 0.xx.  How do you use it?  

Still struggling on segment number.  "The number of segments determine how coarse/fine grained data (ie, old windows) are expired."  I thought retention period determined when they expire?  More segments = less data deleted when a segment expires.  But what determines a segment expiring? Retention Period?

Comment: Windows#until: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Windows.html#until-long- -- The retention period defines the time, but data is expired in segments (ie, "batches"). Example: retention period is 24h, and you have 3 segments. Thus, one segment holds data for a 12h period (it's not 8 hours). If all data of the oldest segments passed the retention time, the whole segment is dropped. Ie, data for 12 hours is expired at once.

Comment: If you define more segments for a given retention period, the segments are smaller and thus data is dropped "earlier" (ie, in smaller batches). For the example above, the oldest data in the segment that is dropped, is basically stored for 36h, because is there for 12h longer until the new data within the segment also ages out.

Comment: So if I have a retention period of 6 hours and define 7 segments.  An hour of data will be dropped every hour?  But does this mean I can access something for 6.5 hours ago? Which is outside the retention period?

Comment: From a performance perspective, I am trying to figure out how to optimize. If I have more segments I delete smaller amounts of data more often (more overhead), but If I have less segments deletes will be larger and fewer.  If disk space is not a concern, guess it comes down to how fast RocksDB can do get/puts on a larger set of data.  What is your recommendation on numbers of segments for a 6 hour retention period?

Comment: Are the retention period and window size in milliseconds or seconds?  Docs are unclear (https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/Stores.html#persistentWindowStore-java.lang.String-long-int-long-boolean-)

Comment: `But does this mean I can access something for 6.5 hours ago? Which is outside the retention period?` -- yes, retention period is a lower bound guaranteed up to 2.0 release (this actually changed this in 2.1 and make the access strict -- the underlying segment mechanism is still the same; we basically only lock down read/write access). -- The default number of segments used by the DSL is 3. -- Retention period and window size are both in milliseconds (the new 2.1 API fixed the unclear semantics).

Comment: If you put a new value for a existing key does the retention period get reset using the current time as the new time?

Comment: For windowed aggregations, retention period is based on window-end time. If you put a new key, into an existing window, it won't change anything, because window-end-time will be larger than record timestamp anyway -- and if a new window is created, it has a new window-end-time and thus will be purged later.

Comment: The documentation says "Put a key-value pair with the current wall-clock time as the timestamp into the corresponding window".  If my retention period is 2 hours, I do .put("a","b").  Then an hour later I do .put("a","c").  From that point, would I be guaranteed 1 or 2 hours more house that "a","c" will be in the state store.  Shouldn't the second put move the key from one window to a newer window?

Comment: I just realize, that the docs are incorrect and miss leading: (1) incorrect, because the default timestamp used, is the current "stream time" (not wall-clock time). (2) miss leading, because it's only called `timestamp`. --- Good new, the JavaDocs is already improved in upcoming 2.1 release. The passed in timestamp, is the `windowStartTimestamp` -- a windowed stored is designed, to store a window per key per entry, with key+windowStartTimestamp being the primary key of the store.

Comment: Thus, when you do the second `.put("a","c")` it will be inserted based on it's event-time and assuming that event-time progressed, it will effectively be put into a different window. When KafkaStreams uses this API, it always uses `.put(K key, V, value, long timestamp)` all to explicitly set the timestamp for the write---the passed in timestamp is the computed window-start-timestamp for the corresponding record. Does this make sense?